# R question: How to do a calculation of a mean off multiple columns and select variables to save in a dataset

Tags: r

I am using a R's default dataset Orange to ask a question.

```
mydata<-Orange
mydata$average_2items<-rowMeans(mydata[,c("age", "circumference")],na.rm=TRUE)
mydata %>% 
  select (circumference,average_2items,age)->x2
```

This all worked, but I want to know how to do the last three lines in one line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
x2 <- transmute(mydata, circumference,
                average_2items = rowMeans(cbind(age, circumference)),
                age)
```

(whitespace notwithstanding, one line of code)

Comment: Wonderful!  It worked very nicely.  Also I was able to do rowMeans multiple times in the same code and create more than one mean variables, which was great.

Thank you!